# Oracle : group results by occurence

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping

I'm having some issue with a specific select in Oracle :

Let's say we have a select returning those elements :

```
Person Evaluation Date         Hour

Bryan  A          10/12/2013   9:00

Ed     D          10/12/2013   9:00

Julia  A          10/12/2013   9:00

Will   F          10/12/2013   9:00

Bryan  B          10/12/2013   14:00

Ed     C          10/12/2013   14:00

Julia  A          10/12/2013   14:00

Will   C          10/12/2013   14:00
```

I want to be able, in my query, to increment a value for each occurence of a specific element, juste like :

```
Person Evaluation Date         Hour    Nb

Bryan  A          10/12/2013   9:00    1

Ed     D          10/12/2013   9:00    1

Julia  A          10/12/2013   9:00    1

Will   F          10/12/2013   9:00    1

Bryan  B          10/12/2013   14:00   2

Ed     C          10/12/2013   14:00   2

Julia  A          10/12/2013   14:00   2

Will   C          10/12/2013   14:00   2
```

I tried dense_rank() with an over(partition by xxx order by xxx), but I only got that :

```
Person Evaluation Date         Hour    Nb

Bryan  A          10/12/2013   9:00    1

Ed     D          10/12/2013   9:00    2

Julia  A          10/12/2013   9:00    3

Will   F          10/12/2013   9:00    4

Bryan  B          10/12/2013   14:00   1

Ed     C          10/12/2013   14:00   2

Julia  A          10/12/2013   14:00   3

Will   C          10/12/2013   14:00   4
```

Comment: Partition is to restart the ranking for a new group.. or rank as subset..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `partition by` clause:

```
dense_rank() over (order by xxx)
```

In your case, that would be:

```
dense_rank() over (order by "hour")
```

Comment: And what if I don't have the hour column ? Can I have the same result just because there's two occurences of each person ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  The question is about an `hour` column which is all over the question.  If you have a question about enumerating occurrences of "person", ask another question with appropriate sample data and desired results.